# Performance Scanning Big Rasters in GeoTIFF Format?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, geotools, performance

I am scanning large rasters in GeoTIFF format. The size is around 30GB and there is only one band. I'm using geotools to do that. I did some experiments on scanning the whole raster to find the best way to do this and realized that performance varies greatly. I don't know if these rasters were tiled. This is the code I used:

```
file file = new File(path);
GridCoverage2DReader  reader = new GeoTiffReaderCached(file);
GridCoverage2D coverage;
ParameterValue<OverviewPolicy> policy = AbstractGridFormat.OVERVIEW_POLICY.createValue();
policy.setValue(OverviewPolicy.IGNORE);
ParameterValue<String> gridsize = AbstractGridFormat.SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE.createValue();
gridsize.setValue("512,512");
ParameterValue<Boolean> useJaiRead = AbstractGridFormat.USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD.createValue();
useJaiRead.setValue(true);

try {
      coverage = this.reader.read(new GeneralParameterValue[] { policy, useJaiRead});
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

RandomIter iter = RandomIterFactory.create(img, null);

//here I iterate either row by row or tile by tile. this is for reading
//values row by row
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        rl.iter.getSample(j, i, 0);
    }
}
```

In the experiments, I change between reading row by row or tile by tile and change between specifying a value for suggested tile like (512,512) or just leave it as is (the tile will be a row by default). Here is the four different ways and their timings:

1. With no tile suggested; reading values row by row: timing (sec) = 328.
2. With no tile suggested; reading values tile by tile: timing (sec) = 42334 (the worst).
3. With tile suggested (512,512); reading values row by row (ignoring the tiles): timing (sec) = 4295.
4. With tile suggested (512,512); reading values tile by tile: timing (sec) = 3409.

The best performance was for the first approach.

Why is that, and will it be true for all rasters?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to explicity state the file format (which appears to be GeoTIFF) and whether any special options where used in file creation (like tiling, and if so, what tile size).  It appears the row by row access is faster because the file is untiled.

Comment: I don't know if these rasters were tiled.

Comment: Row access performance will degrade if the rasters are tiled, just as tile access will improve. The most recent edit to your question has actually made it off-topic for the focused Q&A used here at GIS SE.  Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand what makes an appropriate question..